# Alias osm tag to openstreetmap

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can we get the [osm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osm) and [openstreetmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openstreetmap) tags merged as aliases one direction or the other? They refer to the same thing but seem to have separate followings. The OSM community typically uses just "osm" but in the context of this site for people unfamiliar with the project it might make sense to have "openstreetmap" be the primary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've merged the tags into 'openstreetmap' as I think its a little more telegraphic for unfamiliar users as you mentioned.